# Possible to have multiple `manifest.json` for PWA?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, polymer-starter-kit

Consider I have:-

- PWA at `myapp.firebaseapp.com` with it's own `manifest.json`.
- Admin for the PWA at `myapp.firebaseapp.com/admin`

Is it possible to have another `manifest.json` for the admin URL to allow "Add to Home Screen" on the same PWA?

Answer (score 25):

Sure; the manifest for a given page is determined by the presence of a [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) with details about the manifest's location.

Assuming you have full control over the HTML for `/admin` and for all other pages, you can include `<link rel="manifest" href="/path/to/admin-manifest.json">` in the HTML for `/admin`, and `<link rel="manifest" href="/path/to/user-manifest.json">` in the HTML for other pages.

Each of the manifests can include, e.g., a different [`start_url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest#start_url) value so that they take the user to a different initial page.

Comment: FYI, I am using Polymer Starter Kit, which is a SPA (Singe Page Appilcation) serving from `index.html` with one `manifest.json`. Would putting 2 `<link rel="manifest"> linking to 2 different `manifest.json` works?

Comment: I'm trying to do same thing in my Angular application, but only first included manifest is considered & rest are ignored. Any idea why?

Comment: I tried to find an authentic source to cite but couldn't. You can only link to one manifest per page.

Answer (score 4):

Old questions, but I want to add to the conversation in case anyone else gets here via Googling - It's possible to remove the start_url completely from your manifest, and the default behavior should be to open your PWA to whatever page the user was on when he saved the app to the device home screen. This ended up being a better solution in my case, ymmv.

Comment: does that also work for singlepage apps? (e.g. a create-react-app)