# Is it possible to set PWA Add-to-Home button different for different tenants in a multi-tenant platform?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, multi-tenant

Assume, in a multi-tenant platform, where domain name is same but a tenant is identified by a tenant id (won't have a folder in same name nor tenant's html under it, so 'scope' I doubt it will work, because every page here works for every tenant),
like in this simple e.g., 'www.mysite.com?id=abccompany' for a tenant 'abc company' & while 'www.mysite.com?id=xyzcompany' for a tenant 'xyz company', 
1) can I give different add-to-home text+logo when each of the urls are opened? 
that directs to 
2) Whether I can have different manifest & serviceworker? 
or 
3) achieve it though same service worker but different manifest, notification channel & add home text+logo?
Or limited by one domain one add-to-home?
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Hi... Were you able to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If you check out Google's brief on [The Web App Manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/) you can see they are referenced with a simple `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">` link.  If your app/server can read the query parameter "id" and update that link accordingly with a unique manifest file based on the id, you may achieve what you are looking for.

You may also want to read [Possible to have multiple `manifest.json` for PWA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203661/possible-to-have-multiple-manifest-json-for-pwa)

Comment: 1. I am able to get set different manifest file for each tenant, & on page load I am getting respective manifest for the tenant in context. 2. start_url i set with respective tenant id, for each tenant, say 'www.mysite.com?id=xyzcompany' so that also fine. But, **Service Worker getting registered is once for all tenants** (in the above case, once for abc & xyz), though Service Workers to install Add-to-Home & receive notifications remains different for each tenant. Once a tenant's Add-to-Home is done, it is not prompting for Add-to-Home for any other tenant's home page opened in same browser.

Comment: @Hursh You may need to check the domain name while installing the service worker.