# Progressive Web App Install Prompt is not coming on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, progressive-web-apps

I have created a project, basically a progressive web app wherein application is created dynamically through admin panel.I have root app where structure of app is created and when application is created through admin panel I am creating app id wise manifest file which gets imported on app when app is open.
When I run one of the created app on chrome browser on laptop Install prompt is appeared. Also when I run another app with other id with same root files but with different manifest, I got the install prompt. Both app installed successfully on laptop.However in case of mobile chrome browser, when I run first app then app gets installed after clicking on Install prompt. But, when I run another app I am not getting Install prompt.Instead I am getting option of "**Open In Previous Installed App Name**". 
Please help in it.
I want to come install prompt in second case also.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: yes its there with https url.

Comment: And the lighthouse tool shows no issues in the PWA section?

Comment: Yes , its not showing any issue.Let me explain u the scenario again. I have admin panel from which I am creating a shop.Suppose I have created 2 shops , A & B.When shop is created I am creating start url for the same which is different for both shop and which will be there in manifest.Now when I run the url for shop A in mobile chrome browser, I got the install popup and I install the app. Now , I also have url of shopB. when I run shop B url , I am not getting the install popup. Instead , its showing option in the chrome option browser as ""Open with shop A".

Comment: For shop A and shop B, I have same source code. just there are separate manifest for both and data in html is dynamically getting loaded with HTTPS services.

Comment: hey @Mathias ...any suggestions

Comment: If you are trying to do multiple manifests for the same URL, you may need to search for that. I have only used one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203661/possible-to-have-multiple-manifest-json-for-pwa